# Not able to pick the value of dynamically created Second textbox with the same name

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a page in which i am creating a dynamic textbox element(newComment) box by iterating a loop inside  getMessages() method so my loop is creating two text boxes and calling addComment() method in the loop and trying to fetch the value of second textbox inside addcomment() . but i am not able to get the value of second textbox as it picks value on first text box only .
Can you please suggest what i have to do to correct this and other approach also to fix this.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>profile page</title>

<script src="/WebServices/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"><       </script>
```

```
function showProfile(){
    var profileName = sessionStorage.profileName;

    var url="rest/profiles/"+profileName;
    //alert(profile.profileName);

    $.ajax(
            {
                type:'GET',
                url:url, 
                dataType:'json',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success:function(data)
                {
                            $("#getprofile").append("<b>profileName:</b>"+data.profileName);
                            $("#getprofile").append("<b>firstName:</b>"+data.firstName);
                            $("#getprofile").append("<b>lastName:</b>"+data.lastName+ "<br/>");
                            //$("#getprofile").append("<br/>"+'<input type="submit"   value="'+data[i].profileName+'"onClick="getProfile();return false;">'+"<br/>");
                            $("#getprofile").append("<br/>"+"<a href='#' onclick='getMessages();'>My Messages</a>");
                            //<a href="url">link text</a>

                }
            }
    );

}   


function getMessages(){ 
    $.ajax(
            {
                type:'GET',
                url:'rest/messages', 
                dataType:'json',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success:function(data)
                {
                        for (var i=0;i<data.length;++i){
                        var responseData=JSON.stringify(data);
                        //alert(data.comment);

                            $("#authResponse").append("<br/>"+"<b>MessageId:</b>"+data[i].id);
                            $("#authResponse").append("<b>Message:</b>"+data[i].message);
                            $("#authResponse").append("<b>Author:</b>"+data[i].author+ "<br/>");
                            $("#authResponse").append("<br/>"+'<a href="#" onclick=getComment(\''+data[i].id+'\');>view Comments</a>'+"<br/>"+"<br/>");
                            $("#authResponse").append('<input type="text" name="newComment" id="newComment"/>');
                            $("#authResponse").append("<br/>"+'<input type="submit"   value="Add comment" onClick="addComment(\''+data[i].id+'\');return false;">'+"<br/>");


                        }
                }
            }

    );
}


function getComment(messageId){

    var getCommentURL="rest/messages/"+messageId+"/comments";
    alert(getCommentURL);
    $.ajax(

        {
            type:'GET',
            url:getCommentURL,
            dataType:'json',
            contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success:function(data)
            {   
                if($.trim(data))
                {
                    for (var i=0;i<data.length;++i){
                        $("#getComments").append("<b>Id:</b>"+data[i].id);
                        $("#getComments").append("<b>Comment :</b>"+data[i].message);
                        $("#getComments").append("<b>Author :</b>"+data[i].author);
                    }
                }else{
                    alert("No comments are added for this message.!!")
                }
            },
            error: function (error) {
                  alert('error inside getComment method');
            }   
        }   

    );
}
function addComment(messageId){

    //var comment = $("input#newComment").val();
    //var comment= document.getElementById('newComment').value;
    alert("comment:"+comment);
    var postCommentURL="rest/messages/"+messageId+"/comments";
    var authRequest = {"message":comment,"author":"system"};

    $.ajax(
    {
            type:'POST',
            url:postCommentURL,
            data:JSON.stringify(authRequest),
            dataType:'json',
            contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success:function(data)
            {       
                    for (var i=0;i<data.length;++i){
                        alert("yo");
                        $("#addcommentResult").append("comment has been added successfully.!!");
                        if(data[i].id!=null){
                            $("#addcommentResult").append("comment has been added successfully.!!");
                        }
                        else{
                            $("#addcommentResult").append("comment not added.!!");
                        }
                    }
            },
            error: function (error) {
                  alert('error inside addComment method');
            }   
        }   

    );

}
```

```
My Profile<br/><br/>
<div id = getprofile></div>
<div id = authResponse></div>
<div id = getComments></div>
<div id = addcommentResult></div>
```

Comment: The element's name and ids are always the same, they should be unique. I suggest adding the ID in there.

Comment: can you give example.? thanks .

Comment: So at some point you are doing this:
$("#authResponse").append('<input type="text" name="newComment" id="newComment"/>');
I suggest adding the ID in there, something like:
$("#authResponse").append('<input type="text" data-id="'+data[i].id+'" name="newComment" class="newComment"/>');
Also note I changed the id to a class (because you can have more than one of those). So now when you want to get the value you can use this:
var comment  = $(".newComment[data-id="+messageId+"]").val();
I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. i did the same thing and i am able to get the value of respective textbox .